# Why do clients broadcast SSID's and can you disable it?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid

When a WiFi client is not connect to a wireless network and looking for WiFi networks to connect to, the client broadcasts a list of known networks. I know that this is so that it can connect to networks that have SSID broadcast disabled, but are there any other reasons the client sends the known network names? If that's the only reason, is it possible to prevent the client from broadcasting known SSIDs? It seems like a massive privacy violation, and I don't use any hidden networks (and most people I know don't use them either), so this feature seems pretty useless (for the end user).

Comment: Yes, you can. No, it's not useless, there are broader perspectives on the use of networks and the value of SSIDs within that. But this site is about electronics design...

Comment: "When wifi is disabled, and the client is looking for wifi networks, it broadcasts a list of known networks." Can you clarify this? By client do you mean AP or device connecting to AP? Whichever you mean, the rest of this sentence doesn't quite make sense to me, perhaps I'm missing something

Comment: Yea, I don't get this. Are you saying that computers and phones and other devices LOOKING for wireless networks to connect to will broadcast a list of the wireless networks they've found so that other clients can see those lists without scanning for the available networks themselves? Please use the Edit button and make your question more clear.

Comment: Sorry, i made a typo, I'm referring to active scanning per dirkt

Comment: *"client broadcasts a list of known networks"* - where does the client get this list, and when & why does it broadcast them? A client (especially in a new area) won't have a list of local SSID's to broadcast. This question [just raises further questions...](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/141/585/5b2.gif)

Comment: @Xen2050 That list would necessarily be populated by SSIDs of which the client has previous knowledge, namely networks to which the client has previously connected (and saved said connection details).

Answer (score 6):

This is called [active scanning](https://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/what-are-passive-and-active-scanning):

> The reason for client scanning is to determine a suitable AP to which the client may need to roam now or in the future. A client can use two scanning methods: active and passive. During an active scan, the client radio transmits a probe request and listens for a probe response from an AP. With a passive scan, the client radio listens on each channel for beacons sent periodically by an AP. A passive scan generally takes more time, since the client must listen and wait for a beacon versus actively probing to find an AP. Another limitation with a passive scan is that if the client does not wait long enough on a channel, then the client may miss an AP beacon.

So "can connect to a network that doesn't broadcast its SSID" isn't the only reason.

And yes, it's normally not needed, and yes, it's a massive privacy violation (tracking smartphones through this is easy), and yes, in principle, it can be turned off. Whether your OS or smartphone provides an easy way to turn it off is another story ...

And this observation is nothing new; people have complained to smartphone manufacturers about this already years ago.

Comment: While this is true, I think it is confusing given the original question. The OP believes that the client is sending probe requests to _specific_ AP's, but I read your link as saying that the client _broadcasts_ probe requests and listens for any responses. I don't know which is correct. Could you clarify?

Comment: @bitsmack Clients can [do *both*](https://www.cwnp.com/802.11-mac-series-ndash-basics-mac-architecture-ndash-part-3/); they can send a probe request directed to any AP owning a specified SSID, or send a "wildcard" probe request that will cause all listening APs to respond.

Comment: *it's [active scanning] normally not needed...* Why do you say this? Aren't directed probe requests necessary to aid in successful client roaming, something that's often needed?

Comment: Active scanning can *aid* in client roaming, but is not *needed* or *necessary* - my Linux laptop only does passive scanning (by choice), and can roam just fine. Even if the hardware doesn't support scanning all channels for beacons while connected on a particular channel, you can either initiate such a passive scan manually (pausing the established connection for a short time), or the current connection becomes so weak that the hardware switches to passive scan by itself.